# pyenv vs. homebrew ipython versions and comint

Tags: ipython, comint

In order to solve various probelms with `eglot` and completions, I made sure that both python and pip are set respectively within emacs to `~/.pyenv/shims/ipython` and `~/.pyenv/shims/pip`, as they are in my terminal.

But now, I have another problem: whenever there is output in the shell, there is no newline after it (see below).

I tried advising comint-preoutput-filter and comint-output-filter but none of this helped.

However, the problem disappears if I `(setq python-shell-interpreter "/opt/homebrew/bin/ipython")` instead of `"~/.pyenv/shims/ipython"`.

I use `-i` and `--simple-prompt` as arguments in both cases of course.

[image: No newline after output]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a 'direct' solution to your problem, but generally you don't have to run the language server in a virtual environment. Instead, you should configure the server to use some virtual environment (for the completions). For eglot, the usual way to do this is via a [directory local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) (see [here](https://joaotavora.github.io/eglot/#Project_002dspecific-configuration)). Also, to configure a virtual environment for the python shell (`M-x run-python`), I think you should configure the `python-shell-virtualenv-root` variable.

For example, for the python language server you should configure [jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to use some virtual environment by creating a .dir-locals.el file with something like the following lines (these lines also set your `python-shell-virtualenv-root`, of course this might result in the 'no newline' problem you are describing but I don't know how to fix that problem. Maybe just use the standard python interpreter)

```lisp
((nil (python-shell-virtualenv-root . "~/path/to/root/of/virtualenv")
      (test-test . python-shell-virtualenv-root) 
      (eglot-workspace-configuration
       :pylsp (:plugins
               (:jedi
                (:environment "~/path/to/root/of/virtualenv"))))))
```

see [here](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/blob/develop/CONFIGURATION.md).

If you are using pyright, then you can find more info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

The lines above should work for pylsp, but consult the [eglot docs](https://joaotavora.github.io/eglot/#Project_002dspecific-configuration) for how to configure eglot more specifically.